# Run script against all txt files in directory and sub directories - BASH

Tags: bash

What im trying to do is something along the lines of(this is pseudocode):

```
for txt in  $(some fancy command ./*.txt); do
some command here $txt
```

Comment: I cant figure out how to use a for loop to run something against .txt files in the current directory and sub directories. The subdirectories are more important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.txt" | while read txt; do
  echo "$txt";   # Do something else
done
```

Comment: I  wanted to use find but that just returns the first result, im trying to get all the .txt files with their full path names one on each line, which find can do.. i just cant seem to make it go deeper than the first directory

Comment: @user2967825 The above example would get all `*.txt` files at all levels within the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . | grep ".txt" | xargs -I script.sh {}
```

find returns all files in the directory. grep selects only .txt files and xargs sends the file as Parameter to script.sh

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-exec` option to `find`:

```
find /usr/share/wordlists/*/* -type f -name '*.txt' -exec yourScript {} \;
```